# Can I save my python-statemachine to file?

Tags: python, python-statemachine

Using the python-statemachine package, I would like to save the current state to external file or database, preferably in json format, and later load it to recreate the state. Is this possible, and if so, how would I do it?

Comment: take a look at https://python-statemachine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/persistent_model_machine.html?highlight=save

Comment: Thanks @SembeiNorimaki ! I browsed the documentation, but didn't find this. Should really not be in the examples section. At least that's not where I looked. :)

Comment: @johan, can you tell me where do you expected to see this information so I can improve the docs? Since you asked here, I'm considering turning this a built-in feature. That do you think?

Comment: @FernandoMacedo, thank you for a great lib! I have just started looking at it, but enough to decide keeping using it. The possibility to save and restore the state is a requirement to me, so that's why I asked early on. Of course, built in support would be great, but workarounds are good enough. The Domain Model documentation is a little thin, and that's what you hook in to when saving, so maybe I'd expect the documentation there.